# How to extract a Font Family name on uploading a font file (TTF and/or WOFF)?

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a web-based tool to set up dynamic UI config for another generically formatted web app. It allow the user to specify basic UI colours, images,etc. Additionally, it allows the user to upload a (TTF or WOFF) file containing a custom font.

I would like to be able to interrogate the uploaded font file and dynamically  show the font Family Name, to allow visual confirmation that the correct font file has been uploaded. I'd also like to show some text in the uploaded font, as additional confirmation.

The UI is written in AngularJS.

Is this feasible *within* the browser, or is a call back to back-end (.NET) the only solution...?

Note: I'm not asking for a full solution (that would take all the fun out of it!) but an indication of whether this is even possible and maybe a pointer or two would be gratefully received.

cheers

Comment: I would advice to add some code into your question. It will increase the chances of receiving help and reduce the chances to have your question flagged and closed.

Comment: Strictly speaking.. I'm not (no longer) a coder.. so I have no code to share....

I was hoping for some answers along the lines of either... 

 'this is impossible within the browser...server-side only...' 

or 

 'try looking at library-x...it does just what you want...'

At this stage, I'm just trying to work out if this is a feasible requirement...or whether I should push back on it...